# Could 'otwards' or even 'hotwards' ever be accepted into the language?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, slang, is-it-a-word

I've just woken early from a vivid dream. (must be the local ale - we are in Yorkshire at the moment). I was in an inferno of an industrial kitchen where they were manufacturing 'ready-meals'. One large individual with rolled up sleeves and sweat pouring down his arms was shouting above the din. Portion-sized food was going past on conveyors. Some was going toward ovens and some away from them. The noisy director of operations was shouting instructions for all he was worth. One word that he kept saying baffled me and, I couldn't fathom its meaning. It sounded like 'otwards'. Then I realised that what he was saying was 'hotwards'  (he had a Cockney accent so it sounded like 'otwards) meaning in the direction of heat, or the ovens. When I awoke it occurred to me that this might be a good question for you folk. Is 'hotwards' an acceptable word in the English language?

Comment: It's a word that someone named Gav Thorpe has written in books, but he's doing [that thing where one makes up words that one imagines people in fantasy worlds would need to describe the fascinatingly different events in their fantastical existences](http://xkcd.com/483/).

Comment: Are you asking if people on Yorkshire actually have a word that sounds that way?

Comment: Whatever gave you that idea? By the way, it should be 'IN Yorkshire'. Yorkshire is a county of England, not a ship in mid-Atlantic.

Answer (score 1):

As much as we like to impose our rules, the reality is that language definitions will eventually follow language usage. New words are introduced into the English language all the time. Start using it. If it catches on, then maybe it'll make it into the Oxford English Dictionary some day. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you. The possibilities are endless. Skywards, waterwards, dangerwards, pleasurewards etc.

Comment: Or perhaps just **wards:** *noun* : a section in a hospital for patients needing a particular kind of care *from m-w.com* ;-)

Answer (score -2):

- (fourth line) "towards oven" ; "toward" is static (very frequent confusion in the USA)
- why not "ovenwards" ?